# What ways can you monitor all changes made on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, ssh, monitoring

Sometimes we have contract developers that need to do work on the server (via `ssh` or `sftp`) and I've been looking for ways to monitor what they do on our Debian based server. We have ways of limiting access (restricting access by IP) so they only have access when we have them working on something but we would like to be able to monitor sessions in a way that we can see what they did (possible on desktop but I'm not sure if this is possible on a Linux server).

Sometimes contractors need privileged access to troubleshoot problems which may mean they can change `nginx` configs or modify databases. Privileged access also gives them the ability to add malicious code (logic bombs, etc) or break stuff by accident without knowing what they did to break it.

LXD isn't a good enough option because it doesn't monitor key entries and the resources contractors need access to (entire php web application stack) is the asset. So if they break it, we have to switch to a backup web server anyway. While `chroot` can be used to limit what the user can do, it's not a monitoring tool.

The `history` file in Linux can be modified by the user and even if it couldn't be modified, it doesn't show commands run after entering a prompt (like after entering `mysql` or opening a file). Adding `git` to the root of the system has the same limitations.

We have a server that has the production database and native scripts for the website that we can quickly switch to in an emergency. But without a way to inventory who's had access AND exactly what they have done, tracing blame or even defining what was done is a nightmare.

**Options I've Looked at:**

- [This option](https://gravitational.com/blog/how-to-record-ssh-sessions/) acts as an *authorized MIM* and records `ssh`
  session info on a proxy server. This is very similar to what I was
  saying would be ideal in my comments. I haven't tested this yet.
- Similar option by [ezeelogin](https://www.ezeelogin.com/kb/article/record-ssh-sessions-208.html) but like the above option, i don't see a way to manage file changes over `sftp` so i'll have to test to find out if this is supported.

What solutions are available for this?
Are there any reliable key-loggers that can be used for this?
Are there any enterprise solutions for this?

Comment: It's worth reading law #6 of the ten immutable laws of security: https://www.marshall.edu/it/departments/information-security/10-immutable-laws-of-security/

Comment: @ConorMancone, "A computer is only as secure as the administrator is trustworthy"...the circumstances facing the people you can trust today, might change such that you can't trust them tomorrow. If a logging solution exist for this, at least I'll be able to record every move they make all the way up to the point they write a FW rule to block my remote monitoring scripts, or whatever else, at which point i can kill their connection via the cloud firewall, shutdown the host, and investigate.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I'm all for putting in logging and security where you can.  However, if you're talking about root it is still quite tricky.  After all, if they realize you are logging them, they may very well be able to delete/modify the log.  Unless you are talking about "live" logging, aka actively monitoring what they are doing.  Even that is not entirely fool proof.  Either way, if you want to log everything they do, you should make sure the log is being saved in an *external* system live, and is uni-directional.

Comment: unidirectional meaning that the log is sent from the server to your logging system, and, the logging system being external, the server has no ability to modify/delete anything from the logging system.

Comment: I agree. A lot of the methods I've looked at are not fool proof. Definitely looking for live logging and the logs being remote. I feel like the most ideal solution would be like an ssh tunnel proxy and the proxy records every key stroke on its way through the tunnel. Something similar to how LFCS exams are performed through. And for `sftp` it would simultaneously write the files sent to the intended destination as well as to a files log directory on the proxy server. I feel like this has to be possible.

Comment: Doing it at the SSH level seems like a good bet.  By the time they get in, there are so many different "avenues" they can take to try to avoid detection.  Then again, the trouble with logging every key stroke from SSH is that you lose context - without *seeing* what they are doing, innocuous keystrokes might seem dangerous and vice versa.  It's definitely a tricky game.

Answer (score 1):

Two different approaches could be used.

File integrity monitoring.

Host based intrusion detection software such as AIDE can be configured to record hashes of important files on the system and then perform periodic scans to report on files that have changed.  In your case, if the contractors sometimes have root access, some steps would need to be taken to ensure they could not modify the hashes to avoid changes being detected.

Audit logging

The Linux `auditd` Daemon can be configured to log all commands run by an administrator.  As described in this question;
In https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers

In this case it would be wise to use syslog to send the logs to a remote server that the contractors do not have access to in order to prevent them tampering with the logs.